# C# проверка выбора значений в combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, циклы

У меня имеется,возможно, слишком простой либо глупый вопрос, но я так и не решил его.
Имеется форма с комбобоксами. Кнопка для создания шаблонов документов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При заполнении первого комбобокса Property1 и нажатии на кнопку создания - происходит создание файла в CAD системе с шаблоном из выбранного значения.

А вот при выборе и первого и второго Property2 происходит сначала создание первого файла, а потом второго. Ибо срабатывает первое условие.

Код прикрепляю:

```
if (cb_property1.SelectedIndex == 2) 
    {
                var part1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "RES\\PROFILE.CATPart";
                document_2 = documents1.NewFrom(part1) as MECMOD.PartDocument;
                
                MessageBox.Show("Done!");

    }
if (cb_property1.SelectedIndex == 2 && cb_property2.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "RES\\EX.CATPart";
        document_3 = documents1.NewFrom(path) as MECMOD.PartDocument;
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
```

Как можно реализовать проверку? Чтобы не срабатывал первый цикл,если заполнены оба.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверяйте сначала второе, более специфичное условие, а потом уже первое, причём в ветке `else` (или `else if`):

```
if (cb_property1.SelectedIndex == 2 && cb_property2.SelectedIndex == 4)
{
    // логика при втором условии
}
else if (cb_property1.SelectedIndex == 2) 
{
    // логика при первом условии
}
```

Ну или, поскольку частично условия совпадают, то лучше так, но опять же сначала второе условие проверять:

```
if (cb_property1.SelectedIndex == 2)
{
    if (cb_property2.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        // логика при втором условии
    }
    else
    {
        // логика при первом условии
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде работает!